# mongodb, $sum after $push, how to use it?

Tags: mongodb

i want to write pipeline code, that gives me 5 results of the people who tweeted the most amounts of time. The output should be like i tried in my $project part:

I have problems with using $push, i dont know if i need $sum as an addtion and if so , how to use it in mongodb. This is what i got so far :

```
 [{
                "$group":
    {          
                "userId": "$user.id",
                "$push": {"texts": "$text"},
                "count" : {"$sum": 1}                  
      }},


      {"$sort" : {
        "count": -1
      }},
{
  "$limit": 5
    },

 {"$projekt":
  {
    "userID":"$user.id",
    "count" : "count",
    "tweet_texts" : "$text"
   }


}

]
```

the error i am getting is :

twitter.$cmd failed: exception: the group aggregate field 'userId' must be defined as an expression inside an object

I have watched a lot of videos and i think i generally understand the concept of the pipeline, but $push right now is foggy to me. I hope someone can shed light on it or even better, provide a link to extensive tutorials , so i can learn on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for.

```
[
  {$group:
    {
      _id: '$user.id',          //  For each user.id
      texts: {$push: '$text'},  //  Add user.id's tweets to an array
      count: {$sum: 1}          //  Count user.id's tweets
    }
  },
  {$project:
    {
      _id: 0,                // Don't show _id field
      userId: '$_id',        // Rename _id to userId and show it
      count: 1,              // Show the count field
      texts: 0,              // Don't show texts field
      tweet_texts: '$texts'  // Rename texts to tweet_texts
    }
  },
  {$sort: {count: -1}},  // Sort on count field descending
  {$limit: 5}  // Limit to the first 5 docs
]
```